# Поиск в большом тексте

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки, search

#### Описание

Есть у меня большой текст и моя задача в том чтобы при вводе что-то в поле ввода программа начала искать совпадения с текстом и возвращала `index` совпадений.

Вот мой код -

```cs
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [TextArea]
    public static string FullText;
    public List<int> MatchIndex;

    /*------------------------------ Functions ------------------------------*/
    public void FindText(string PartOfText)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PartOfText))
        {
            if (FullText.Contains(PartOfText))
            {
                MatchIndex.Add(FullText.IndexOf(PartOfText));
                Debug.Log("Есть совпадения.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Совпадения не найдены.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но тут проблема в том что он находит только первое совпадение.

#### Вопрос

Как мне найти все совпадения?

Comment: Не нужно задавать несколько вопросов в одном, пускай даже с пометкой `не обязательно`. Лучше задать 2 разных вопроса.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно регуляркой.
Указываем пространство имён:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Код:

```
var pattern = Regex.Escape(search);
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var indexes = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Index).ToList();
```

`input` - текст, в котором ищем,
`search` - что ищем,
`indexes` - результат, список индексов.

Comment: Ваш ответ хороший, только добавьте в начале что за библиотеки которые нужно добавить.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void FindText(string PartOfText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PartOfText) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullText)) { return; }
    for (int i = FullText.IndexOf(PartOfText); i > -1; i = FullText.IndexOf(PartOfText, i + 1)){Debug.Log(i);}
}
```

И я бы засунул это всё дело в корутину с yield return  в цикле.

Comment: Ваш вариант хороший, но ответ "Alexander Petrov"-а работает быстрее. Не обижайтесь. Вместо галочки я вам плюс дам.